# How to limit the product quantity for specific items in magento

Tags: magento

I'm setting up a Magento site for a client who sells Fabric and other related materials.  There is a minimum of .5 yard for any one Fabric product, After that, it can go to any amount, but the minimum is .5. Currently I'm able to type in .25, .125, etc. and add those to the shopping cart.

I only want this to apply to the Fabric products (there are around 2000 different fabric products) but not to the other types she sells on her site, like Rulers, needles, buttons, etc... I don't want people to be able to purchase .5 buttons.

Thanks

Comment: you can limit the 'minimum quantity' of a product in the shopping cart by editing the value on the 'Inventory' tab in product infromation when editing a product.

Comment: Its not letting me enter in a decimal for this.

Answer (score 0):

You might need an observer for this that monitors the `checkout_cart_product_add_after` event. This event passes the following parameter:

```
array('quote_item' => $result, 'product' => $product)
```

Here, you could check the quantity via `quote_item` and the product's category (if it's fabric or not) via `product`. What I imagine you could do here is remove the specific quote item from cart if it is a decimal value and not a member of the 'Fabric' category.

Good luck.